# responsive web design: where to start (css modules)

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

Lately i've been reading a lot about RWD (responsive web design), and would like to try to develop a template (for starters). The books that i'm reading are quite outdated (published in the end of 2011), so obviously some code provided doesn't work properly as for the case of css3 flex box module. After researching for a while i found out on Mozzila's developers that Flex Box module will be changed soon.

My question is: What are the most time and performance efficient CSS3 modules to work with for RWD? and any heads-up that i should be careful with?

Besides CSS3PIE are there any good solutions to add css3 functionalities to outdated browsers?

Comment: Have you ever heard of bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com?

Comment: Recommend reading FAQ on how to ask a good question.  Asking how to do RWD is too broad.  For adding css3 shims for old browsers see Modernizr

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of sounding mean, SO shouldn't be used to solicit opinions.
However, in the spirit of learning and sharing knowledge, a couple of great places to start would be taking a look at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) or [Zurb Foundation.](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

Both are two really great frameworks that will help you create responsive sites. Although they do pretty much the same thing, they are actually two very different frameworks. I'll let you decide as to which one to use.

Another great resource I've found is looking at RWD pattens. Both [HTML5 Rocks](http://html5rocks.com) and [Brad Frost's Blog](http://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/) have certainly helped me out.

Good luck.